# Alerts software when exchange rates spikes or dips

Tags: currency-converter

I'm looking for an application/website that can send me alerts (email or SMS) when exchange rates spike by some percentage. For example I want to receive an alert when the rate between DKK and EUR changes more than 2 % compared to the previous day. I found some tools that let you set up alerts if the value becomes larger then some absolute value, but i'm specifically looking for the change in percentage. I would want to set this up for multiple exchange rates.

Best if its free, but if it costs a small amount that is OK too.